# Multi level index dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
   Repo Averages for 25 Apr 2018    

Business Date   Instrument
25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
25/04/2018  R_RAGB_1.15_10/18
25/04/2018  R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
25/04/2018  R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
25/04/2018  R_RAGB_1.95_06/19
```

I am looking to drop levels and get a dataframe similar to

```
  Business Date Instrument
    25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
    25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
    25/04/2018  R_RAGB_1.15_10/18
    25/04/2018  R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
    25/04/2018  R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
    25/04/2018  R_RAGB_1.95_06/19
```

I have asked this question before and I know that I should be using `df.columns.droplevel(1)` but this time it does not work I get an error

```
AttributeError: 'Index' object has no attribute 'droplevel'
```

it is very strange that I get this message because in the same script i use similar trick to drop level. Yet for this dataframe it does not work. I am a bit puzzled,

In python the output looks like this

Out[226]:

```
    Repo Averages for 25 Apr 2018           Unnamed: 1
1                   Business Date           Instrument
2                      25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
3                      25/04/2018  GC_AUSTRIA_SUB_10YR
4                      25/04/2018    R_RAGB_1.15_10/18
5                      25/04/2018    R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
6                      25/04/2018    R_RAGB_4.35_03/19
7                      25/04/2018    R_RAGB_1.95_06/19
```

Help is appreciated

Comment: Can you out put df .columns here

Comment: @Wen modified my question to add additional info on the output

Comment: This is not multiple index , see my answer : -)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not multiple index , try following

```
df.columns=df.iloc[0,:]
df=df.iloc[1:,:]
df
```

Comment: the answer you suggested  does not lead to a dataframe where I can select 'Business Date' and 'Instrument'.